# How to get the databases set up when Publishing an ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, razor

I made a web application out of a blank Razor template and now I need to deploy it to my web server. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do things in the correct order so that I can have my database tables made set up. The reason I'm having trouble is that I can't remember what was already there when I first got the template and what was created when I first ran Build Solution.

My understanding is that

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MyProjectName-20150506095501.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MyProjectName-20150506095501;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

will, when I Publish my project, create all the tables `_MigrationHistory`, `AspNetRoles`, etc. that come with the template inside the database that referred to by that `connectionString` (or were those all there when I got the template? I don't remember). The extra tables that I need I will have to manually create in that same SQL database and then use my

```
[Database]
public class PortalData : DataContext
{
    public PortalData()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public Table<AssetLink> links;
    public Table<AssetFile> files;
    public Table<Organization> orgs;
    public Table<Category> cats;
    public Table<UserClearance> clearances;
    public Table<Extension> extensions;
```

as a Model for those tables `links`, `files`, `orgs`, etc. that I created with a query. Then `_MigrationHistory`, `AspNetRoles`, etc., and `links`, `files`, `orgs`, etc. will all live in the same database that I've created beforehand.

Is that right? Or can someone give me a brief explanation of what's supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.All tables will live in the same database that I've created beforehand.  _MigrationNistory an auxiliary database that stores changes made during the EF6 if the models does not correspond to the structure of the database. I deleted it. If the structure of the database is fully corresponds to the model - it does not appear any more. Other tables (AspNetRoles) need to be able to authenticate users on your web application. Sorry for my English))